# TextView wont show Html

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I created an activity where I have there a TextView to display Terms and Conditions.

In order to do so, I write in Html.

For example I tried this:

```
<string name="Terms_Title">
    <h3>2. Use License</h3>
    <ol type="a">
       <li>Permission is granted to temporarily download one copy of Apps per device for personal, non-commercial transitory viewing only. This is the grant of a license, not a transfer of title, and under this license you may not:
       <ol type="i">
           <li>modify or copy the materials;</li>
           <li>use the materials for any commercial purpose, or for any public display (commercial or non-commercial);</li>
           <li>attempt to decompile or reverse engineer any software contained in Apps;</li>
           <li>remove any copyright or other proprietary notations from the materials; or</li>
           <li>transfer the materials to another person or "mirror" the materials on any other server.</li>
       </ol>
        </li>
       <li>This license shall automatically terminate if you violate any of these restrictions and may be terminated by Apps Team at any time. Upon terminating your viewing of these materials or upon the termination of this license, you must destroy any downloaded materials in your possession whether in electronic or printed format.</li>
    </ol>
</string>
```

and the result is:

[image]

I tried also to use:

```
tv_Terms = findViewById( R.id.tv_Terms );
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    tv_Terms.setText( Html.fromHtml(getString( R.string.Terms_Title ), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else {
    tv_Terms.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString( R.string.Terms_Title )));
}
```

But it just doesnt work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

TextView is not a HTML browser. Also Html class docs clearly state that magic won't happen either:

> This class processes HTML strings into displayable styled text. **Not all HTML tags are supported.**

If you need richer HTML support use WebView instead.